# How to chain properties using Binding with Dependency Property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding, dependency-properties

Assume the following data-flow happens using Binding:

```
PropertyA <--> DependencyProperty <--> PropertyB
```

- The <--> marks represents a `TwoWay` binding mode.
- Both `PropertyA` and `PropertyB` classes implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and invoke `OnPropertyChanged` method in their setter accessor when changed.

The binding compiler setting starts from the above flow left side to the right, that means the last binding set is between `DependencyProperty` and `PropertyB`.

The problem is when `PropertyA` notifies for property changed, `DependencyProperty` doesn't invoke her `OnPropertyChangedCallback` method.

On the contrary, when `PropertyB` notifies for property changed, `DependencyProperty` DOES invoke her `OnPropertyChangedCallback` method.

I would like to know if it even possible to achieve such behavior using the .NET Binding mechanism, or there is another way.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE**

The term "chain" in the question context, for example, means:

when `PropertyA` notifies for a change, `PropertyB` will be notified from `DependencyProperty` which notified from `PropertyA` change, and vice versa.

The above example "chains" between `PropertyA` to `PropertyB` using `DependencyProperty`.

Comment: Reading your title : do you want to achieve some kind of concatenation ?

Comment: Emmanuel DURIN thank you for your answer, yes I do ("...or there is another way.").

Comment: That's really not visible in your question - or I missed something - Do you want to concatenate PropA and PropB ? - Are they strings ? Or do you want any change happeing to A or B change the dep. prop( that would have strange side effects) ?

Comment: Emmanuel DURIN I updated the question for clarity.

Answer (score 2):

You ***can't have two bindings on the same `DependencyProperty`*** being the target.

It would mean that you 'd have two sources for the same `DependencyProperty`.

But ***you can have a property*** (on the Model or ViewModel) being the ***source for many dependency properties***.
That's pretty common.

It seems normal to me if you ve got the `OnPropertyChangedCallback` called only when one property is changed.

There can be only one source, and the last binding wins.

Here is a nicepage with schemas :  http://blog.scottlogic.com/2012/04/05/everything-you-wanted-to-know-about-databinding-in-wpf-silverlight-and-wp7-part-one.html

**EDIT**

If you want to have two properties of two objects in phase, you can use ViewModel as an intermediary between A holding PropB and B holding PropB.

So you'd have :
                           | <--> ClassA.PropA
View <--->  ViewModel.Prop-|
                           | <--> ClassB.PropB

It means : 
 - ViewModel Object would register to the PropertyEventChanged of ClassA and ClassB.
ViewModel would raise an event if  ClassA or ClassB would raise an event for PropA or PropB change.

- ViewModel would call ClassA.PropA.set and ClassB.PropB.set when ViewModel Prop.set would be called.
- When get of ViewModel, only ClassA.PropA would be read. But it wouldn't matter because PropA and PropB are worth the same.

Hope it helps, regards

Regards

Comment: Thank you for your answer, please assign an link with your answer so I know it is based upon either the language specification or some reliable source.

Comment: Two-way or not doesn't even matter. A single dependency property can't be the target of two Bindings at the same time. The question doesn't make sense.

Comment: @Eido, I found no wording there is only one source for dep.prop. The closest reliable source is Clemens (46K reputation). But it can't work with two source for a dep.property. It would mean the dep.prop could be valued by two properties with two different values at the same time

Comment: @Eido. I made an edit. Maybe I understood what could help you. Please have a look when you have time.